# How to extract data from complex function in R

Tags: r

The `acf` method in the `stats` package returns a complex output. For example

```
x = rnorm(1000, mean=100, sd=10)
acf(x)
```

returns a plot. If I do

```
acf_x = acf(x)
acf_x
```

it returns

```
Autocorrelations of series ‘x’, by lag

     0      1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8      9     10     11 
 1.000  0.000 -0.031 -0.002 -0.052  0.017 -0.014  0.030  0.011  0.002 -0.044  0.000 
    12     13     14     15     16     17     18     19     20     21     22     23 
 0.055 -0.007  0.049  0.025 -0.027 -0.048  0.033  0.027  0.043 -0.007 -0.010  0.025 
    24     25     26     27     28     29     30 
-0.083  0.045 -0.074  0.016  0.041 -0.046  0.010
```

If I look at `class(acf)` it returns `'acf'`.

How do I extract the autocorrelation versus lag into a data_frame?

More generally, when presented with a function that returns a complex object, how do I extract the data from it, i.e. is there a general pattern for this type of function?

Comment: Relevant: [Extract numeric value from ACF in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9440588/extract-numeric-value-from-acf-in-r)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deschen's answer to the original question gives the general response - how do I discover the elements in a complex model object: `str()`. One can also use the `names()` function for S3 objects, where the result lists the names one can use to extract elements from the `list()` with the `$` or `[[` forms of the extract operator.

```
set.seed(95014)
x = rnorm(1000, mean=100, sd=10)
acf_x <- acf(x)

names(acf_x) 

> names(acf_x)
[1] "acf"    "type"   "n.used" "lag"    "series" "snames"
>
```

Since the `acf` and `lag` elements are stored as arrays, we'll need to extract just the first dimension to obtain a simple vector. We can accomplish this by chaining the `[` form of the extract operator onto the object that is generated by the `[[` extract on the model object.

```
head(acf_x[["acf"]][,1,1]) # second extract returns a simple vector

> head(acf_x[["acf"]][,1,1])
[1]  1.000000000 -0.034863150  0.037745441 -0.020464290 -0.004974406
[6]  0.016770363
```

In this case R performs the extraction left to right - first `acf_x[["acf"]]` is evaluated, and then `[,1,1]` is applied to the result.

For the concrete part of the question, "how do I create a data frame with this data?" One can create a data frame with the output from the `acf()` function as follows.

```
set.seed(95014)
x = rnorm(1000, mean=100, sd=10)
acf_x <- acf(x)

results <- data.frame(acf_value = acf_x$acf[,1,1],
                      acf_lag = acf_x$lag[,1,1])

head(results)
```

...and the output:

```
> head(results)
     acf_value acf_lag
1  1.000000000       0
2 -0.034863150       1
3  0.037745441       2
4 -0.020464290       3
5 -0.004974406       4
6  0.016770363       5
```

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the help function of acf via `?acf` you'll see under "value" what the output will look like.

In this case, the acf object is a list with several elements.

If you e.g. want the lags, you can simply access this via:

```
my_lags <- acf_x$lag
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```r
str(acf_x)
```

or

```r
print.default(acf_x)
```

This will get you an idea how the object looks like internally and how to access the elements in it.